# Stream blob data from a stored procedure call

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am trying to stream a blob that is returned from my stored procedure call. I am trying to do this using springs AbstractLobStreamingResultSetExtractor.

```
public OutputStream getDocument(final Document doc, final OutputStream outStream) { 

    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(rdcJdbcTemplate)
    .withProcedureName(PROC_NAME)
    .withCatalogName(CATALOG_NAME)
    .withSchemaName(SCHEMA_NAME).declareParameters(new SqlParameter(DOC_ID_PARAM, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
            new SqlOutParameter(OUT_PARAM, OracleTypes.BLOB , new AbstractLobStreamingResultSetExtractor<Object>(){

                @Override
                protected void streamData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException,
                        IOException, DataAccessException {

                    InputStream blobStream = lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, 1);               
                    if (blobStream != null){                    
                        FileCopyUtils.copy(blobStream, outStream);  
                    }       
                }
            }));

    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(DOC_ID_PARAM, doc.getId());

    Map<String,Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    return outStream;
}
```

When i debug this the streamdata code is never called.

Any ideas of how i might implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future readers I have found a solution to this

```
public OutputStream getGlasDocument(final Document doc, final OutputStream outStream) {             

    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(rdcJdbcTemplate)
    .withProcedureName(PROC_NAME)
    .withCatalogName(CATALOG_NAME)
    .withSchemaName(SCHEMA_NAME).declareParameters(new SqlParameter(DOC_ID_PARAM, OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
            new SqlOutParameter(OUT_PARAM, OracleTypes.BLOB, null, new SqlReturnType() {

                @Override
                public Object getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int paramIndex,
                        int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
                    try {
                        Blob blob = cs.getBlob(1);
                        if (blob != null){
                            FileCopyUtils.copy(cs.getBlob(1).getBinaryStream(), outStream);
                        }                           
                    } catch (IOException e) {                           
                        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }));

    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue(DOC_ID_PARAM, doc.getId());        
    simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    return outStream;
}
```